# ngClass function inside ngFor issue

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ngfor, ng-class

Here is a really simple `ngFor` `loop`.

**html**:

```
<div class="button" *ngFor="let button of buttons">
<button [ngClass]="{\'red\': testColor(button.id)}"
                (click)="changeColor(button.id)">
        test {{button.id}} - {{button.color}}
</button>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
testColor(id){
  for(let i=0; i<this.buttons.length; i++){
    if(id == i){
        console.log('test1');
                return this.buttons[i].color;
      break;
    }

  }
}
changeColor(id){
    for(let i=0; i<this.buttons.length; i++){
    if(id == i){
        console.log('test2');
                this.buttons[i].color = !this.buttons[i].color;
      break;
    }

  }
}
```

See the  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sshu3md0/)

When I click on the button, the "test2" works fine (it is called only 1 time), but "test1" (from the function in the `ngClass`) is called 5 times, even with a breaker.

I guess it's due to the `ngClass`, but how can I make it be called only for the clicked element?

Comment: I see the "test2" printed only once in the dev tools console in every case

Answer (score 0):

It's because your console is in the for, so the break works as expected, if you click on the first button, it will stop after one iteration but if you click on the fifth one, it will break after the fifth one.

Anyway, the for are useless, you can do :

```
testColor(id){
  return this.buttons[id].color;
}
changeColor(id){
  this.buttons[id].color = !this.buttons[id].color;
}
```

You can even skip the testColor:

```
<button [class.red]="button.color" (click)="changeColor(button.id)"> 
    test {{button.id}} - {{button.color}}
</button>
```

Comment: Well, the console show 5 "test 1", I want it to show only one.
Also, your code is doing the same, the function testColor() is called 5 times.

Comment: I updated my answer with something better and way lighter !

Answer (score 0):

Functions in view bindings are called every time Angular runs change detection and is therefore usually considered a bad idea.

The preferred way is to assign the result of the function call to a field and bind to that field instead.
If you use `*ngFor` you usually want an field that holds an array of values.

Bind to it using

```
<div class="button" *ngFor="let button of buttons; index as i">
<button [ngClass]="{'red': testColors[i]"
                (click)="changeColor(button.id)">
        test {{button.id}} - {{button.color}}
</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually there is no difference between this and what I did. Also the right way to write it is "let i = index" but it doesn't change anything. In that case index or button.id have the same value.
In my real code the function testColors() is way bigger than that and I would like to avoid to call it a lot of times

Comment: In my example `testColors` should be an array not a function as explained in my answer. I didn't understand what you try to accomplish with your colours therefore didn't try to come up with code to create an array.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. but that's not really my question. My question was: when I have  a test function in the ngClass, it's called 5 times. How can I have it be called 1 time. Is it possible?

Comment: it's not really possible and it's definitely the wrong approach. There might be ways that I would consider hacky to achieve that, but that is advanced change detection tuning. You might tune CD later anyway when you understand it better, but binding the result of a function to a property or attribute, especially if the function does more than the most basic calculation is just not how you use Angular bindings.

Comment: Angular calls the function every time it runs change detection, there is nothing you can do about it, all you can do is to limit when change detection is run, but for your use case that will be already quite complicated to control "manually" when change detection should run.